# An error was encountered during the evaluation of the row level security expression

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I'm using Azure analysis services with Power BI Embedded.

When viewing embedded reports in our portal, I intermitantly get the below error:

> An error was encountered during the evaluation of the row level security expression defined on table  Error message: Cannot convert value 'undefined' of type Text to type Number.

Most of the time, the reports function correctly and the row level security is applied correctly. Refreshing the page can clear the error.

Is there anything that can be done to avoid the error appearing?

**Edit:**
adding my row level security filters (each line is a new table)

```
=ISBLANK('A'[c]) || 'A'[c] = VALUE( CUSTOMDATA())
='C'[c] = VALUE( CUSTOMDATA())
='U'[c] = VALUE( CUSTOMDATA())
='F'[c] = VALUE( CUSTOMDATA())
```

Comment: Can you post here the expression used in the role definition?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov no problem, done